# Accessing /run/user/xxxx/gvfs

Tags: 18.04, permissions, xorg, root, fuse

I am trying to read files from the gvfs directory as root user after I start an x server with `sudo xinit ./myscript -- :1`.

I keep getting permission denied error. I tried allowing other users and allowing root in `/etc/fuse.conf`, switching to a user with `su user`. They didn't work. It is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there a way I can access the mounted devices as root user or can I log in as a user after `xinit`?

If I exec `whoami`, I still see `root` even after`su user`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
su user &

whoami &

cd ../../run/user/1000

ls gvfs
```

It seems it is not possible to change users from a shell script. It is possible to run commands as another user with `-c` flag.

So just `su user -c /path/to/script.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to `su user -c /path/to/script.py`, is to disable auto mounting and use `jmtpfs` or similar tools to mount the device to another directory.